# Display colour from html code read in from database

Tags: html, asp-classic, db2, background-color

I have written a simple `asp` command that is retrieving HTML colour codes from a database and these are being displayed in a table as so -

```
<table border="1" width="75%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
end if
%>
</table>
```

Is there a way that in the column that holds these individual HTML colour values, to have the background of their specific cells to be set to their respective colours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing your value as background color

```
<table border="1" width="75%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields
response.write("<th>" & x.name & "</th>")
next%>
</tr>
<%do until rs.EOF%>
<tr>
<%for each x in rs.Fields%>
   <td style="background-color: #<%Response.Write(x.value)%>;"><%Response.Write(x.value)%></td>
<%next
rs.MoveNext%>
</tr>
<%loop
rs.close
conn.close
end if
%>
</table>
```